# View file properties browsing search results in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse I can search through all files of a project and browse the search results using up- and down-arrows. 
Is it possible to set up a view that displays information like date of last modification about the recently selected file? I'd like to see these information at once. I don't want to right click the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Properties view will show the properties for the currently selected item. For a file the properties include the last modified date.

Show the view with 'Windows > Show View > Other... > General > Properties'

Comment: I didn't know about that view. Helps alot. Thank you. It sadly does not refresh when browsing the Search result using the arrows in the Search view.

Comment: You can get it to update from the Search view by dragging one of the views to a different view 'stack' so that both views are visible.